# Would we be able to hear aliens talk?

Tags: biology, aliens, xenobiology

If we were to encounter alien species of, lets say approximately the same size as us, **would there be any reason to expect them to communicate in the same frequency ranges as us?**

Human beings have a [frequency range that we hear in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearing_range#Humans), and a [range that we talk in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocal_range). **Is there anything special about this range?**

I'm thinking perhaps:

- Those frequencies easier to produce by biological constructs.
- Hearing those frequencies is more useful for other survival aspects.

Comment: Are we to presuppose aliens that use sound for communication? Have you considered other *Earth* creatures, which can hear both lower and higher frequencies and have different tolerance spans for amplitude?

Comment: For a land-based air-breathing creature, developing the ability to hear more than one octave or so _below_ the human hearing range would be hard; an ability to hear much more than three octaves _above_, while imaginable, would be mostly useless because there are few natural ways to make such sounds. This means that _if_ the _human-sized_ aliens can live in our atmosphere we could probably hear them at least partially. For example, dolphins communicate using a range of frequencies of which we can hear only the lower part; we can hear _some_ of the sounds made by dolphins, but not all of them.

Comment: I edited your question, hopefully it still retains the original intent (feel free to roll it back otherwise) but I believe it was being interpreted as many questions where it was actually displaying some thought around the topic. I also put the question first as this gets the reader into the right mindset to start applying the information you then give them.

Comment: @AlexP why not post as an Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we have plenty of animals, even mammals, on Earth which create higher or lower frequencies than we can hear. There tends to be some cross over with the frequencies we hear but the fact that we have instances of it occurring on Earth means it would almost certainly happen on another planet.

On another planet the composition of the atmosphere, gravity and air pressure would all, most likely, be different - these would all effect how vocal chords would evolve there and produce a different frequency range in our atmosphere.

That doesn't mean we wouldn't be able to hear them, just probably not all of the sounds they make. Though in our atmosphere they might not be able to hear them either.

Comment: Do you have an idea if having either lower / higher atmospheric pressure or a less / more dense composition would effect the general what alien human range could hear and speak at?

Answer (score 4):

The [Fuzzies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Fuzzy) have ultrasonic voices, not as a consequence of being smaller than us (they’re not *that* small), but to make their communication intentionally inaudible to most other animals.  Hunters can talk to each other without alerting prey.

Bats make ultrasonic noise, not because their throats are so small, but because it makes for useful sonar.  If they were to develop speech it would probably start with the complex vocal control they already have.

Elephants communicate using infrasonic calls not because their size requires them to make only low notes, but because it can be heard through woods — the tree trunks are small compared to the wavelength.

So it is quite concevable that aliens will use sound that is beyond our range of hearing.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything special about this range?

No there isn't, it's just a product of our physical traits.